# Finding 2 words using LIKE even not in chronological order

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I just want to display description with word **ROMEO JULIET** even it is not in chronological orders.

```
ID   DESC
1    This is a sample sentence created by romeo and juliet
2    This is a sample sentence with romeo juliet.
3    romeo and juliet.
4    How to query romeo juliet word.
5    This is not included because there no name here.
```

In the sample above, i want to display id 1 to 4, because it contains words romeo juliet.

How can i do that using LIKE ?

I tried below query

```
SELECT DESC FROM TableName WHERE DESC LIKE '%ROMEO JULIET%'
```

but the result is only id 2, since the names in id 1,3 and 4 is not chronological order.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try `SELECT DESC FROM TableName WHERE DESC LIKE '%ROMEO%JULIET%'`

Comment: Chronological order? Where is the time element in your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for a statement where you search for ROMEO AND JULIET

You can write in SQL like this

`SELECT... WHERE DESC LIKE '%romeo%' AND DESC LIKE '%juliet%'`

Comment: will it returns if the text contains either romeo or juliet

Comment: @bmsqldev no, for that you need 'OR' in stead of 'AND'. The rest of the query remains the same

Comment: @WardC , this one is the best.. i'll mark this as answer.. Thanks you so much for the help.

Answer (score 3):

You can ask for both combination:

```
SELECT DESC 
FROM TableName 
WHERE DESC LIKE '%ROMEO%JULIET%' 
OR DESC LIKE '%JULIET%ROMEO%'
```

Comment: @WardC's answer is better because it can be easily extended to more words, while this one needs a lot more writing with 3 words (6 conditions), or with 4 (24 conditions) etc.

Comment: Also, most databases will have better performance with AND than with OR (because each statement reduces the resultset in stead of making it bigger)

Comment: Yeah @marmarta and WardC are correct. I just replied for this particular question. But you're right about performance and scalability.

Comment: I just use WardC in my query and works perfect.. but this one also working.. thanks @aquiros

Answer (score 1):

if u want to show desc having `romeo` and `'juliet'`

try this

```
SELECT DESC FROM TableName WHERE DESC LIKE '%ROMEO%JULIET%'
```

Comment: @wardc didn't understand

Comment: your query will not find 'How to query juliet romeo word.' I interpreted the OP 'even not in chronological order' like that. Maybe I'm wrong